# If $(Q_3-Q_2)=\frac34(Q_2-Q_1)$, then

Tags: statistics, quantile

If $(Q_3-Q_2)=\frac34(Q_2-Q_1)$, then

1. There are more data which are less than the median value
2. There are more data which are less than the modal value
3. There are less data greater than the mean value
4. There are more data more than the median value
5. There are less data greater than the median value

**My Try**

I tried to find median $Q_2$ in terms of $Q_1$ & $Q_3$   $$Q_2=\frac{3Q_1+4Q_3}{7}$$
Also I know that in general, $$Q_2=\frac{Q_1+Q_3}{2}$$

All I can understand is that this has something to do with the mean. I'm completely lost in this problem. Can you please help me.

Comment: Assuming $Q_i$ is the $i$th quartile, what does $Q_3-Q_2<Q_2-Q_1$ tell you about the skewness of the distribution?

Comment: Or pehaps look at [Bowley's measure of skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Quartile-based_measures).

Comment: I'm confused about the wording here. What does it mean when they say "less data" or "more data"? As an example if we take MARKS obtained by 11 students in a class, median MARK is the 6th student's MARK. So we have "equal data" on both sides regardless of their MARKS. Please explain this for me.

Comment: All I can say is that this is a negatively skewed distribution where it is generally true that mean<median<mode. Looks like option #2 is a possible answer, but I am not sure of the wording here either.

Comment: Since, $Q_2 = \frac{3Q_1 + 4Q_3}{7} = \frac{Q_1 + Q_3}{2}$ => $Q_3 = Q_1$ so $Q_1 = Q_2 = Q_3$. Which means, the median is same as the middle values $Q_1 =Q_2=Q_3$. doesn't that help?

Answer (score 1):

Now ,if the graph was symmetric then $Q_2 = \frac{Q_1+Q_3}{2}$ but for the given set $Q_2 = \frac{3Q_1+4Q_3}{7}$

Determining quartile skewness; 
$$B_1=\frac{\frac{Q_1+Q_3}{2} - \frac{3Q_1+4Q_3}{7}}{\frac{Q_3-Q_1}{2}}$$

then we have $$ B_1= \frac{\frac{Q_1-Q_3}{14}}{\frac{Q_3-Q_1}{2}}$$ $$B_1=\frac{-1}{7}$$

[image: 1]]

Therefore the graph is negatively skewed,Hence there's a majority of data ***less than mode of the distribution***

Option 2# would be the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But according to this, Option 1 & 2 both seems legit. How do you explain it?

Comment: The value of the skewness coefficient is very less.Hence the distribution curve will most likely remain very close to the symmetric curve.But as the peak value of the curve is always the mode, even when the graph is shifted slightly Option 2, will always be valid. but nothing can said for certain with regard to the median.therefore option 1 is not 100% accurate. if a graph of skewness coefficient $\frac{-1}{7}$ was drawn this would be clear.